# image doesn't want to show after an URL change

Tags: php, image, url

Before I used this Url (www.website/all_file/profil.php?u=username) to get in the profile and all the informations show perfetly including the profile image.

But when I change the URL for (www.website/all_file/profil.php/username) to get in the profile, it show me the information, but it doesn't show me the profile picture of the user

Here is the code for the url (www.website/all_file/profil.php?u=username):

```
$uss = $_GET['u'] ;


$m = "SELECT username,image_user,about,contact FROM database.users WHERE username= '$uss' "; 
       $de = mysqli_query($database_connection,$m);



      while($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($de)){

       $cnt = $rows['contact'];
       $abt = $rows['about'];
       $usern = $rows['username'];
       $img = $rows['image_user'];


 echo $cnt;
 echo $usern;      
 echo <img width='100' height='100' src='image_users/".$img." '>;
```

In the url (www.website/all_file/profil.php/username) code, I just change $uss = $_GET['u']  by $uss = 'username';

The file that stock the users profile pictures is (images_users) and profil.php is before the images_users file. The problem is not the database because the image is already in. 
Thanks

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection, you need to fix this.

Comment: And how can I fix it?

Comment: I know that I must add $uss = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['u']); but I don't have $uss = $_GET ['u'] any more,  I have $uss = 'username ' take from the URL instead  (www.website/all_file/profil.php/username) .

Answer (score 1):

After you changed your URL, the relative URL does no longer point to the same location as before.

Previously, when the URL was `/all_file/profil.php`, `image_users/$img` pointed to `/all_file/image_users/$img` - since your browser knows that `profile.php` was the file name (everything after the last `/`).

After you changed how you use the path of the URL, the new path is `/all_file/profil.php/username`. When you give a relative URL with this as the base path, your browser believes that `profil.php` is part of the *directory path*. Thus, the browser tries to load your image from `/all_file/profile.php/image_users/$img` - and this fails, since it means that you're attempting to load the profile of an user named `image_users/$img`.

Replace the path you're using with the absolute path to the image instead of using a relative image, and the image should load again:

```
 echo "<img width='100' height='100' src='/all_file/image_users/".$img." '>";
```